# Get all displayed layers currently visible in the map

Tags: openlayers, angular

Angular: 8
Openlayers: 5.2

I am trying to build a dynamic legend that only shows the displayed layers in the map. With a getLegendGraph from mapserver I want to create the legend.
This works great when I filter with getVisible and loop through all the layers.
But now i only want to show layers that you can actually see, to build a legend for example a print.

This is what I have tried.

```
    // Loop through all the layers
    this.mapService.map.getLayers().forEach((function(layer) {
        // Filter only the visible layers
        if(layer.getVisible()) {
            // create an array with all the created url's
            for (let i = 0; i < layer.values_.source.params_.LAYERS.length; i++) {
                let tempUrl = layer.values_.source.url_ + "&request=GetLegendGraphic&format=image/png&service=wms&version=1.1.1&layer=" + layer.values_.source.params_.LAYERS[i];
                this.visibleLayers.push(tempUrl);
            }
        }
    }).bind(this));
```

Every layer comes from mapServer.

How can I get all the current displayed layers in the map?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "visible on the map"? Does this mean: any non transparent part of the layer visible in the current view?

Comment: For example there is a river in the map and you can see it, it wil be visible in the legend. But when you zoom in else where and there is no river it wont show in the legend.